# How to get all products of any specific Amazon merchant/seller?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api

I am using searching the whole available internet resources for getting all products of any specific amazon seller/merchant. I have used almost every available Api of Amazon, MWS Reports, MWS Products, Product Advertising Api.

My problem with Each Api.

Product Advertising Api of Amazon does return a generic search results and no MerchantId specific results.

MWS Products Api also gives results generally and not based on specif MerchantId.

MWS Report Api is creating Report for only my MerchantId (The Merchant who created the AWS key, secret). and not return any results for any other merchant.

Once again. I want to get all products from any Amazon Merchant Store based on Merchant Id.

This is my exact competitor [Amazon store Facebook Page tab app](https://www.facebook.com/nerdpicker/app_164750486901460)

At least tell me how they get all products of a specific Merchant.

Comment: Hey Suman , have u  got solution? i am also looking for same.

Comment: Hi looking for same here. I searched hours in AWS documentation. But getting all product info instead of a particular seller or store?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass merchant id in product item search api
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Comment: Please give answer along with an example of how it can be used.